# need to pass a variable from client side to server side JS file using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass a variable from client side to server side JS file using plain javascript

Hi,
I need to pass a variable from client-side JS file to server-side JS file.

my function on client-side looks like this

```
function functionName(){     
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'http://localhost:5500/token';
    http.open("POST",url);
    http.send("pass value from client");
    http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
         if(http.status === 200){
            console.log(http.responseText)
            return true;
         }
    }
}
```

function on server-side JS looks like this
`

```
app.post("/token", async function(req,res){ 
    console.log(req.body)    //this is not working 
    var url = '<some URL>'; 
    http.open("POST",url); 
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8"); 
    http.send();

http.onreadystatechange=()=>{
    if(http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200){
        res.send(http.responseText);
        res.end
    }
}
```

})`

when I try to print the value from server-side, it prints empty value ''.

Note- Im new to Javascript ;)

Comment: You're sending GET request, but reading POST request?

Comment: Your AJAX request goes to `/token`, but the server-side code you have shown us is for the route `/groupON`. So what's the connection between those two supposed to be?

Comment: pls ignore the request names. copied it by mistake.
I have same request names, still facing the issue,

Comment: A GET request [may not have a body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET). The browser isn't sending `pass value from client` to your backend so there's nothing to log.

Comment: even if i change it to POST call, it is sending nothing.

Comment: Is it express? req.body doesn't work out of the box. You need to add app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using express, there are three ways to receive parameters from the client. See this code:

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
// required to actually receive data. See https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

app.listen(5500, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port 5500')
})

// Receive parameter by URL
app.get('/token/:token', function (req, res) {
  const token = req.params.token
  console.log(`token is ${token}`)
  res.status(200).send(`token is ${token}`)
})

// Receive parameter by query string
app.get('/token', function (req, res) {
  const token = req.query.token
  console.log(`token is ${token}`)
  res.status(200).send(`token is ${token}`)
})

// Receive parameter by post
app.post('/token', bodyParser.text(), function (req, res) {
  const token = req.body
  console.log(`token is ${token}`)
  res.status(200).send(`token is ${token}`)
})
```

client.js

```
function getValue (method, uri, data) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var url = `http://localhost:5500${uri}`
    http.open(method, url);
    console.log(data)
    http.send(data)
    http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
        if (http.status === 200){
            console.log(http.responseText)
            return true
        }
    }
}

getValue('GET', '/token/mytoken')
getValue('GET', '/token?token=mytoken')
getValue('POST', '/token', 'mytoken')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a minimal working example using node.js packages http and express on the server-side and and old CommonJS version of node-fetch. Install those via `npm install http express node-fetch@2`

client.js:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');


let data = { foo : 'bar' };


fetch('http://localhost/test', {
    method : 'POST',
    body : JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require('http');
var app = express();

var serverHTTP = http.createServer(app);
serverHTTP.listen(80);

let httpHandler = (request, response) => {
    let body = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    request.on('end', async () => {
       console.log(body);
    });
};

app.post('/test', httpHandler);
```

When I run the server and then the client afterwards this works for me. I would generally recommend not using XMLHttpRequest but the newer fetch, no matter whether you are on node.js or in a browser. If you get this example to work I think you should be able to adopt your code to work in a similar fashion. Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are new to JavaScript, and I assume that you are new to web development in general (Please correct me if I'm wrong, and ignore the rest of this answer).

---

The expression of "Passing a variable from client-side JavaScript to server-side (back-end)" might not be correct, we would rather say that we want to pass a value, since the `client` is running in a completely different environment than the `server`.

Even though you are running both applications in your computer now, but later when you deploy it, the backend application might be sitting on a different server than the one who serves the front-end (client side) JavaScript, then that very "front-end" JavaScript will run from the users' machines.

I would invite you to read more about [How the web works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/How_the_Web_works).

In short, the clients needs to talk to the server through protocols like HTTP (like the one you are using with `XMLHttpRequest`).

Note that you can now use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) since it's highly supported now. But let's continue looking into your code using `XMLHttpRequest`.

From your backend application code, I see that you are expecting a JSON body sent by a POST request, so your client should send something that should be serialised to JSON, i.e it needs a key/value pair.

```
function functionName(){     
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'http://localhost:5500/token';
    http.open("POST",url);
    // tells the server your content-type
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    // makes your send a JSON response with { key: value }
    http.send(JSON.stringify({ message: "pass value from client" }));
    http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
         if(http.status === 200){
            console.log(http.responseText)
            return true;
         }
    }
}
```

*I used this example to refresh my memory: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#example_post.*

Now from the server side, I suppose you use [ExpressJS framework](https://expressjs.com/), make sure that your application can parse `application/JSON` bodies by adding [`app.use(express.json()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/express-js-express-json-function) before your `app.post()` line, so your code will look like the following:

```
const express = require('express');

app.use(express.json();

app.post("/token", function(req,res){ 
    console.log(req.body);
    return res.json({ data: req.body.message })
});
```

And if you want your Node.js+Express server application to perform another HTTP call to another third-party application, you can use either the core-library ([tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-http-client-with-core-http-in-node-js)) or use other libraries like [`axios`](https://axios-http.com/) or [`superagent`](https://github.com/ladjs/superagent). Also note that this approach may have a high cost on your application performance and your user-experience in some cases, especially when your future applications grows :)